# How can I get PHP to include form values when sending an email the first time? (WordPress Admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Advanced Custom Fields within a WooCommerce shop to allow me to populate and include shipping service and tracking number info whenever I fill those values, set the order status to "Completed", and hit update.

However, the values won't hydrate in the email template until the second time because I think the post_meta is not in existence the first time around. Can someone please help me figure out how to get that right away?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 
'woocommerce_email_after_order_table_func' );
 function woocommerce_email_after_order_table_func( $order ) {
 $ship = get_field($order->id, 'shipping_service', true);
 $track = get_field($order->id, 'tracking_number', true);


 $status = $order->get_status();
 $shippingService = get_post_meta($order->id, 'shipping_service', true);
 $trackingNumber = get_post_meta($order->id, 'tracking_number', true);
 $trackingURL = '';
 switch ($shippingService) {
    case "FedEx":
        $trackingURL = "http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?tracknumbers=";
        break;
    case "USPS":
        $trackingURL = "https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction?tLabels=";
        break;

}



if($status == "completed"){
    ?>

    <h3>Shipping Information:</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Tracking Number: </td>

            <td>
            <a href="<?php echo ($trackingURL . $trackingNumber) ?>">
                <?php echo $trackingNumber; ?>
            </a>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $track; ?></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shipping Service: </td>
            <td><?php echo $shippingService; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ship; ?></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<?php 
    $trackingURL = NULL;
    } else { 
?>
    <h3>When we have your order shipped, we will send an email with that information.</h3>
<?php
    }   
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug that code? If you think that some condition applies to the first and second execution (whatever that means - is there any possibility that the given code runs multiple times), why not check that?

Comment: Well the thing is that the advanced custom fields of 'shipping_service' and 'tracking_number' don't take an actual value until after they have been saved. So I'm trying to see if I can display via $ship/$track the raw value of the input fields.

Just seeing them show up would give me confidence enough to know that I could create an if/else statement with the $ship & $shippingService variables [and $track & $trackingNumber variables]

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of your issue or not, but `$order->id` has been deprecated since 3.0 and should be `$order->get_id()`. You can also use `$order->get_meta( 'tracking_number' )`to retrieve the meta. Are you certain the meta is saved?